# VBA Macro triggering too often

Tags: vba, excel

My worksheet is set up with data validation dropdowns and I am wanting a macro to ONLY trigger when the value of the cell is changed from another value in the dropdown, not from the default "empty" value.

Here is what I am trying to use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 5 Then
        If IsEmpty(Target.Value) = True Then
            MsgBox "Test1"
        Else
            MsgBox "Test2"
        End If
    End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Exit Sub

End Sub
```

My problem is that this "IsEmpty" command is reading the cell AFTER the selection not before. I want it to read what the cells value was BEFORE the selection not after.

How can I do this?

Comment: One way to do this is to use the Selection_Change event to capture the "old" value

Comment: And in addition to `Selection_Change` event capturing old value, `Workbook_Open` should also capture it, so that there is an old value on 1st execution of `Selection_Change`.

Comment: Thank you, Tim and everyone. I've gotten this to work!

Answer (score 2):

Example approach:

```
Const COL_CHECK As Long = 5
Private oldVal

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = Target.Cells(1) '<< in case multiple cells are changed...
    If c.Column = COL_CHECK Then
        If oldVal <> "" Then
            Debug.Print "changed from non-blank"
        Else
            Debug.Print "changed from blank"
        End If
    End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Exit Sub

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = Target.Cells(1)
    oldVal = IIf(c.Column = COL_CHECK, c.Value, "")
    Debug.Print "oldVal=" & oldVal
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, a point to note with this general approach is that some actions such as selecting the entire sheet will cause `oldVal` to error out (well, become undefined) due to size limitations. I have fixed this in my work code by identifying if there is an error in `_SelectionChange` and then setting `oldVal` to a manageable value (e.g. `""`). I note that you have fixed that limitation by selecting the first cell but that might not be valid in all cases.

Comment: @AJD Noted - the truth is that handling these types of events robustly is much more nuanced than most people here want to get into (and me too, in this context).  More often than not solutions posted here will not even take into account the possibility of a multi-cell value for `Target`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:
This will need one cell per validation-dropdown:

```
 Function ValChange(Cell2Follow As Range) As String
    ValChange = ""
    If Len(Application.Caller.Text) = 0 Then Exit Function
    If Application.Caller.Text = Cell2Follow.Text Then Exit Function
    MsgBox "value of the cell is changed from another value in the dropdown" & vbLf & "not from the default 'empty' value"
End Function
```

in a different cell, assumed the dropdown is in E6:
=E6&ValChange(E6)

application.caller.text will be the old value
(calculation must be automatic)